# Sunspot is only returning one matching term from and ignoring the rest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I just installed the [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem

This is my setup:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers

  attr_accessible :title, :content, :category_id, :tag_list

  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy


  searchable do
    text :title, boost: 5
    text :content
    text :replies do
      replies.map { |reply| reply.content }
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if signed_in?
      @search = Post.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      #@post = current_user.posts.build
      #@feed_items = current_user.feed.results.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @feed_items = @search.results
    end
    .
    .
    .
```

**routes.rb:**

```
 resources :posts do
    resources :votes
    resources :replies
  end
```

The corrects results are returned when I search for the post `:title` and `:content`. Something weird happens when searching for the replies `:content` attribute.

I searched for 3 different terms in 3 different posts: `scala, groovy, python`. Only `'scala'` is returning something. I even created another reply in another post with the text `'scala'`, but only the first one is returned as a result.

This is the output (only the first one returns a result):

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. I had to do this:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```